# how to calculate individual frame size from a spritesheet

Tags: android, width, frame, sprite, sprite-sheet

How can I calculate width x height dimensions of a single frame from a raw .png sprite sheet? I have this sprite of explosion(5120x128) , and I cannot find a way to calculate width of a single frame from this.

[image]